# Can't upload an image or pdf on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't upload an image or pdf on my codeigniter

This is my view

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label>Upload Gambar</label>
        <input name="foto" type="file" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

This is my controller

```
 function form_pendaftaran_act(){
    $nik = $this->input->post('nik');
    $nama = $this->input->post('nama_anggota');
    $gender = $this->input->post('gender');
    $ttl = $this->input->post('ttl');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $notelp = $this->input->post('notelp');
    $alamat = $this->input->post('alamat');
    $pendidikan = $this->input->post('pendidikan');
    $status = $this->input->post('status');
    $tinggi_badan = $this->input->post('tinggi_badan');
    $berat_badan = $this->input->post('berat_badan');
    $uk_baju = $this->input->post('uk_baju');
    $uk_celana = $this->input->post('uk_celana');
    $posisi = $this->input->post('posisi');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama_anggota','Nama Anggota',
    'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required');


   if($this->form_validation->run() != false){
      $config['upload_path'] = './assets/upload/';
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|pdf';
      $config['max_size'] = '2048';
      $config['file_name'] = 'gambar'.time();

      $this->load->library('upload', $config);

      if($this->upload->do_upload('foto')){
        $image=$this->upload->data();

      $data = array(
        'nik' => $nik,
        'nama_anggota' => $nama,
        'gender' => $gender,
        'ttl' => $ttl,
        'email' => $email,
        'no_telp' => $notelp,
        'alamat' => $alamat,
        'pendidikan' => $pendidikan,
        'status' => $status,
        'tinggi_badan' => $tinggi_badan,
        'berat_badan' => $berat_badan,
        'uk_baju' => $uk_baju,
        'uk_celana' => $uk_celana,
        'posisi' => $posisi,
        'gambar' => $image['file_name']

         );

      $this->m_office->insert_data($data,'anggota');
      redirect(base_url().'member');
      }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata
        ('alert', 'Anda Belum Memilih Foto');
      }
    }else{
      $this->load->view('member/header');
      $this->load->view('member/form_pendaftaran');
      $this->load->view('member/footer');
    }
      }
    }
```

My problem is i can't upload the image or pdf. After i click submit on my view, the web just viewing a blank white screen. But, before i add the image configuration script, the web was doing well

Comment: Have you added this attribute in your form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure the form has the enctype specified or no files will upload.

```
<form action="/route" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Upload Gambar</label>
        <input name="foto" type="file" class="form-control">
    </div>
</form>
```